# Who's Who (Giving/Receiving Structures)

Tags: translation, giving-and-receiving, subjects

I have the following translation for class.

```
旅館には、外国人がたくさんいて、
アメリカから来たテッドさんという人が、
息子に英語の話し方を教えてくれたので、
そのおれいに、車で、神社に連れて行ってあげることにしました。
```

I am having trouble figuring out who goes along with what parts of the sentence.

The first line I think I am fine with.

```
In the Japanese-style inn, there were a lot of people and...
```

The second line I am also pretty confident about.

```
a person called Ted-san who came from America...
```

The third line is where I start having an issue. I thought `...てくれる` was only used when someone was giving/doing something for you (the speaker). Is this not the case? I feel like I want to assign it to the son, and make it the following. But I am not sure.

```
taught my son how to speak English so...
```

The fourth line the only issue I have is knowing what `そのおれいに` means. I know `その` marks "that" and `に` is a particle. I looked up `おれい` and find "thank you". So "to that thank you"? I am guessing it's the following. But not sure how it comes together.

```
to thank him for that, I decided to take him to a shrine in our car.
```

So my questions are.

1. When can `...てくれる` be directed towards someone other than the speaker?
2. How does `そのおれいに` transfer to English?

Thanks :)

Comment: くれる isn't only used when someone gives something to you. It's more of a "giving down". Someone of higher "status" gives to someone of lower "status", or alternatively, someone close to the speaker is being given something. My first thought when reading this (and I could be wrong) is that Ted-san's son is close to the speaker.

Comment: I thought 下さる was used for giving down.

Comment: 下さる is the extremely humble version of くれる。 Usually not used in normal speech.

Comment: I think 下さる is 尊敬語(honorific form) not 謙譲語(humble form). I don't think 下さる is "extremely" polite/formal. I think 息子に英語の話し方を教えて*くださった*ので、そのお礼に車で神社に連れて行って(さし)あげることにしました would be acceptable here. (それと、Tedさんの息子とか関係ないです。>> 「「くれる」「下さる」:与える側が主語、*受ける側が視点*となり、*与える側はソトの人物*に限られる。」[授受動詞](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA%E7%A7%B0#.E6.8E.88.E5.8F.97.E5.8B.95.E8.A9.9E))

Comment: ですので、Tedさん=ソト, 息子(my son)=ウチ, だから「(テッドさん(ソト)が私の息子(ウチ)に～～して)くれる」です。

Comment: If your son benefited from Ted's kindness, you also benefited, so you gave Ted a ride as a token of gratitude.  Is this uniquely Japanese or just universal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your translation (except 外国人 = foreign people)

1. When the action is directed towards someone from your in-group ([内]{うち}/ウチ).
   [Uchi-soto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchi-soto)
2. そのお[礼]{れい}に means そのお礼として, in return (for~). [参考:お礼として in Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E7%A4%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) 
   breakdown:
   その its
   お礼(≒[返礼]{へんれい}, お[返]{かえ}し) reward, return(favor, gift...)
   に/として as